# Probability equations representation in Latex (Bernoulli distribution)

Tags: latex

I have a probabilistic model using Bernoulli Distribution:

[image: model]

I need to do the same representation in Latex in a professional way, I have tried things like:

```
\Bigg\{
```

and

```
\[ \left \{ \begin{tabular}{ccc} \end{tabular}\right \}\]
```

and both of them are not good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maybe be more specific why these two solutions are not good enough.
Anyway, to typeset your equation I would do:

```
\begin{equation}
    f(k;p) =
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{cc}
                p & \mathrm{if\ } k=1 \\
                1-p & \mathrm{if\ } k=0 \\
        \end{array} 
    \right.
\end{equation}
```

`\right.` closes `\left\{` without printing anything.

Comment: thank you very much that what i wanted, my problem was that , i wasn't able to remove the closing curly brackets

Answer (score 3):

Use [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `cases`, because that's what it's there for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  f(k;p) =
  \begin{cases}
    p     & \text{if $k = 1$}, \\
    1 - p & \text{if $k = 0$}.
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```